# Зависает линукс после экрана логина

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, kubuntu, elementary-os

Ставлю линукс на ноутбук, когда при установке выбираешь попробовать линукс (ubuntu) без установки, то все работает нормально. Как только установилось, появляется кнопка перезагрузки, я нажимаю и линукс замирает намертво. Выключаю кнопкой, запускаю, попадаю на экран логина. Ввожу пароль и все, рабочий стол загорелся, но ярлыки не появились и все висит, даже курсор.

Стоит intel i7, nvidia 1050ti, ram 16gb, устанавливаю на hdd в формате mbr
пробовал ставить ubuntu, kubuntu, mint, elementary, deepin, manjaro, в uefi и legacy

Читал разные статьи, пробовал вводить что-то в терминалы, но ничего не помогло.
Уже 2 недели по вечерам пытаюсь установить. Та же винда устанавливается и работает прекрасно.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Зачем вам линукс на такой мощный комп? Ставьте десятку

Comment: @ArturHan у меня есть виндовс на ссд, но в линуксе мне удобней работать

Comment: После того, как наступило зависание, попробуйте нажать комбинацию трёх клавиш: Ctrl/Alt/F1. Теоретически, должно повиться окно консольного входа в систему. Если появилось - заходите, вводите команду *top* и смотрите - кто жрёт процессор. Убейте его и вернитесь в GUI нажав Alt/F7 (А может я уже забыл. - Ctrl/F7)

Comment: Раз у Вас логин уже отработал, значит сетевая карточка уже поднялась. Попробуйте зайти на этот злосчастный ноут по SSH и, опять-же, команда *top* - прибить гада.

Comment: А вообще, раз система не может даже перезагрузиться нормально, то скорее всего, проблема в том, что при установке линуха Вы сделали что-то не то с распределением дисковых разделов. Похоже, что какой-то раздел не может быть размонтирован/монтирован. Вы как распределяли разделы - в ручную? Или доверили это дело инсталлятору? 

После жёсткой перезагрузки появляется меню grub? Ведь у Вас две ОС на ноуте - так ? А когда появляется окно логина - там есть пользователь, которого Вы создали во время установки?

Comment: @Sergey, а вы пробовали у себя нажать Ctrl + Alt + F1? Мне особенно интересно, как это в современных системах сделано.

Comment: @0andriy *вы пробовали у себя нажать Ctrl + Alt + F1?* Разумеется. 8-0 Много раз так делал...

Comment: Точно такая же проблема. Ноут HP OMEN 17-w226ur 3RM81EA
Удалось выяснить из-за чего это происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Была аналогичная проблема в `CentOS 7.6` с `gdm 3.28` после авторизации в `X`. Похоже, что это глюк `gdm`.

1. Открываем вторую консоль: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Запускаем `htop`, находим `X` процесс и посылаем ему `SIGTERM`.

   - <kbd>F4</kbd> набираем `gdm` - чтобы найти `X` процесс
   - <kbd>F9</kbd> ⇒ `SIGTERM`
3. `X Window` перезапустится и со второй попытки `gdm` будет работать нормально.
4. Для входа в систему без авторизации можно добавить в `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

   ```
    AutomaticLogin=username
    AutomaticLoginEnable=True
   ```

---

Дополнительно:

- `gdm` для `gnome`.
- `lightdm` для `xfce`.
- `lxdm` для `lxde`.